# remove attributes from array except a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
var employee = [{"firstName": "something", "LastName":"something", "addresss":"something"},{"firstName": "something", "LastName":"something", "addresss":"something"},{"firstName": "something", "LastName":"something", "addresss":"something"},...]
```

I want to remove all the attributes except address from the above array.

Can anyone give me a solution for this.

Thanks in advance for your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Option 1.*

Loop in array and use `delete` to remove the un-wanted property like

`delete employee[0].firstName`

`delete employee[0].LastName`

*Option 2.*(recommended)

Loop in array and create new object skipping the un-wanted property like

`employee[0] = {'addresss': employee[0].addresss}`

Comment: Thanks, But my problem is, i have more than 10 keys, i have to remove all keys other than address.

Comment: @NatarajanL, I recommend you option 2

Comment: @Aravind, thanks i use the 2nd option and its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `delete` keyword. [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) .

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < employee.length; i++) {
    for (var key in employee[i]) {
        if (employee[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (key !== 'addresss') {
                delete employee[i][key]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is what the code does.  It deletes all keys other than address from the employee array.   It loops thorough the objects keys and checks if it is user created property, then checks if the key is address.  If the key is not address, it deletes the key from the object

Comment: Thanks a lot i didn't see the not symbol in if condition

Comment: Remember that this solution modifies the existing objects.  if you would need the firstName or lastName information after this `for` loop, you will not have access to it.